# Vue unit testing - textContent doesn't contain expected propsData

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, karma-mocha

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{serviceConfig.name}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['serviceConfig']
}
</script>
```

In my test, I am setting serviceConfig like this:

```
    it(`should render serviceConfig`, () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(TestMe2);
    const comp = new Constructor({
        propsData: {
            serviceConfig: '{ "name": "Apple" }'
        }
    }).$mount();

    expect(comp.serviceConfig).to.equal('{ "name": "Apple" }'); // successfull
    expect(comp.$el.textContent).to.contain('Apple'); // unsuccessfull

});
```

However, if I change my template so that I am rendering {{serviceConfig}} instead of serviceConfig.name, it works, but not what I want (since I just want the name, i.e. 'Apple').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a string, not an object, as `serviceConfig`.